# Xcode - Retrieving value from textfield in different viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have 2 viewControllers (NewTicket1Controller and NewTicket2Controller).  View 1 has a text field named 'ticket' and view 2 wants to access that value.

Here is my code in View 2.

```
NewTicket1Controller *screen1 = [[NewTicket1Controller alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", screen1.ticket.text);
```

My NSLog statement above returns null for the ticket textfield value. But it's not null.  If I switch back to view 1 I can see that there is a value in that field.

Can I not retrieve a variable like this?

Comment: Dude, you are working with `C`. And what you are doing is you are creating a new memory reference for your `NewTicket1Controller` in which the `screen1.ticket` object is null, whereas the actual value is existing in already initialized `NewTicket1Controller`you need to just use the memory reference to pass from one controller to another, using properties.

Comment: Passing using properties did cross my mind but I wanted to see if there was an easier way because I have a lot more than 1 textfield value that I want to access.  Thanks iphonic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate a new NewTicket1Controller, all of it's properties are initialized to their default values.  This does not give you a reference to any existing NewTicket1Controller objects.  If you are using storyboards, you can pass it to the other view controller in prepareForSegue, or if you are not using storyboards, you can programatically pass it to the new view controller when it is created, assuming it is created from the NewTicket1Controller.

Comment: Thanks Wyatt.  See my comment in my question above.

Comment: There are really a few different ways you could tackle this.  Without seeing the full implementation, you could use delegation, if that makes sense in your case.  But probably the easiest way to pass a bunch of strings to another view controller would still be to do what I suggested, either in prepareForSeqgue or after programmatically creating your NewTicket2Controller, but wrap all of your data into an NSDictionary and pass the whole dictionary.  Then NewTicket2Controller can parse through that to find what it needs.

Comment: NSDictionary sounds like it makes more sense.  Ill mess with that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need to initialize you view to access it. If you want to send text contained in textfield to another view..You need to store that ticket text field value into a string of other view controller..

At NewTicket2Controller take property with NSString with name ticketString and synthesize it...Then you can use that reference for storing value of ticket at NewTicket1Controller

At button action while switching to NewTicket2Controller..Put some code at NewTicket1Controller

```
NewTicket2Controller *screen2 = [[NewTicket2Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewTicket2Controller" bundle:nil];

screen2.ticketString=self.ticket.text;//if you propertise the ticket textfield

NSLog(@"%@", screen2.ticketString);
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

You just created and inited screen1. Any and all values will be nil or initialized.

A few things:
You want to try to keep the data (model) separate from your views and controller when possible.

You're going to have to provide some connection between the 2 view controllers.
One approach is to set up one as a weak link to the other.

Example for NewTicket2Controller
@property (nonatomic, weak) NewTicket1Controller *delegate;

And then when you create NewTicket2Controller you would assign self.delegate = screen1

After that you could access methods using the delegate.

(Ideally you'd setup a protocol for the delegate)

Answer (score 0):

Others have given you partial answers. Let me state everything at once.

First, never try to manipulate another view controller's view objects directly. That is serious violation of the "encapsulation" principle of object oriented programming. You should treat a view controller's views as private, and add properties or methods to communicate between view controllers.

Second, you are creating a brand new instance of your view controller and expecting to be able to use that new view controller instance to alter settings in an existing view controller. This is like buying a new car that is a perfect match for your existing car, setting the radio station on that new car, and then wondering why the radio station on the old car doesn't change. They are different cars! They are different objects! They may be feature-for-feature identical, but they are different instances of the same object. If you had an identical twin, it is still a different person, right?

You need a way to get a pointer to your existing NewTicket1Controller object. How you do that depends on how your program is set up. Post some info on how you are setting up your view controllers. Are you using a navigation controller? Is NewTicket1Controller your root view controller? How are you getting from view controller 1 to view controller 2? A segue? (assuming you're using storyboards. Tell us if you're not.)

Comment: I understand the whole instance thing now.  NewTicket1Controller and NewTicket2Controller are both part of a navigation controller. NewTicket1Controller is not the root view, but its the second one in the nav controller and NewTicket2Controller is the third.  Im going from NewTicket1Controller to NewTicket2Controller using a button (storyboard segue).

Comment: Ok, have you sorted out your problem then?